# Widgets placing into QGridLayout

Tags: qt, size, width, qgridlayout

I use QGridLayout and define layout as ui file.

I need to implement such layout:

|Column 0                |Column 1   |Column 2                  |Column 3                |

|width enough to fit text|empty space|Line edit with width 66-70|width enough to fit text|

My problem are columns 1 and 2.

Which size policy should I use to give all the free space to column 1?

I am trying to set min width=66 and max width=70 to Column 2. And "Expanding" width policy to Column 1.

But for some reason, in this case column 1 is expanded more shat it should be and Column 2 has less than 66.

If I set size policy for column 1 as "maximum", than all the space is given to column 2. And width of that column is bigger than line edit widget, so it is not right aligned any more.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing everything right except for the units.

I presume that your line edit's width is given in characters, but it seems like you're using that number to set the widths given in pixels.

I would set it the following way:

```
qreal em = QFontMetricsF(ui.lineEdit->font()).width('m');
ui.lineEdit->setMinimumWidth(round(em*66));
ui.lineEdit->setMaximumWidth(round(em*70));
```